# how to interchange sum of series formulas?

Tags: sequences-and-series

I have this formula

\begin{equation}
\sum_{k=a+1}^{b}\frac{b-k+1}{b-a+1}
\end{equation}

I want to convert it to

\begin{equation}
\frac{1}{b-a+1}\sum_{k=1}^{b-a}k
\end{equation}

What are the steps to get this?

Comment: Note $b-a+1$ is independent of $k$, it is a constant with regards to the indexing variable so you can pull that out of the summation and get $\frac{1}{b-a+1}\sum_{k=a+1}^{b}b-k+1$. Now use the substitution $j=b-k+1$.

Comment: How can I do this by substitution?

Answer (score 0):

Following from Anurag A's comment, it will be seen that if you look at the limits of the summation,  (b-a)$\geq$k$\geq$(a + 1), you would want to:

- (To that expression) Negate 'k' and the values on both sides of 'k' and change the signs appropriately.
- Then, add 1 and b to the values, and you'll see this: The middle expression takes the value of 'j', and the left and right expressions become your new summation limits(due to the sign change, the upper limit on the left, and lower limit on the right).

Now, you may simply use 'j' as your summation variable with your new limits and viola, you have your answer.

Edit: If this helped, let us know with a green one (Up-vote). Otherwise, I'll add clarification if necessary.